I can't get the user agent for the device to send a http request in my flutter app
I want to get and send the device user agent in my request.
I looked for some answers and I got that there is a package that gives the device user agent it is called device_info_plus but the issue here is when I want to get the device info (The code is from the pub.dev for the package):
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';

DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();

WebBrowserInfo webBrowserInfo = await deviceInfo.webBrowserInfo;
print('Running on ${webBrowserInfo.userAgent}');

And when I run my app I get this exception:

_TypeError (type 'BaseDeviceInfo' is not a subtype of type 'WebBrowserInfo' in type cast)

Here is my code:
  String _userAgent = '';
  Future<void> _getDeviceInfo() async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();

    WebBrowserInfo webBrowserInfo = await deviceInfo.webBrowserInfo;
    _userAgent = webBrowserInfo.userAgent!;
  }

And the exception happens in this block:
WebBrowserInfo webBrowserInfo = await deviceInfo.webBrowserInfo;
If there is a way to get the user agent without this package is okay.

Where is the code the exception is generated from? Is it what you shared above? Please provide a concise code snippet so people can understand what is going wrong.

Here is my code:
  String _userAgent = '';
  Future<void> _getDeviceInfo() async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();

    WebBrowserInfo webBrowserInfo = await deviceInfo.webBrowserInfo;
    _userAgent = webBrowserInfo.userAgent!;
  }

And I get the exception in:
WebBrowserInfo webBrowserInfo = await deviceInfo.webBrowserInfo;

I have edited the question with my code and where the exception happen

What Flutter version and device_info_plus version are you using?

Sorry fot late reply

here is my flutter version:
Flutter 3.16.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 78666c8dc5 (5 months ago) • 2023-12-19 16:14:14 -0800
Engine • revision 3f3e560236
Tools • Dart 3.2.3 • DevTools 2.28.4
And the package version:
device_info_plus: ^9.1.2
If you need anything more please tell me sorry again for late reply


Have you tried upgrading the device_info_plus to the latest version?

I will try to update it.
